# Antonym: "repetitive"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

Let's say there's a video game that never gets boring no matter how much you play it, because there's always something new to do in it. What would be a term to describe the game?

The opposite would be a "repetitive" game that gets boring quickly, because there's only one thing to do in it.

Comment: The term 'infinitely varied' sounds better than the mathematical 'non-repeating'.

Comment: Note that there are two different ways to interpret "antonym of repetitive".  You could have a sequence of the same elements as before, only in a different, non-repeating (ie, *random*) order, or you could have some new and *unique* elements (vs the same old ones)

Comment: Why don't you coin a phrase... something like "auto-evolving"? Gamers are the only ones who need to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ever-changing](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+ever-changing)

adjective: ever-changing; adjective: everchanging

constantly changing or developing.
*the key is adapting to the ever-changing conditions*

--Google search define operation (ever-changing)

Answer (score 3):

The game is dynamic

I prefer 'dynamic'

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

Enduring

e.g. A book of enduring interest

> Oxford dictionary:
>   lasting for a long time
>   e.g. What is the reason for the game's enduring appeal?

A similar (may be less suitable) option may be

kaleidoscopic

Cambridge dictionary

> quickly changing from one thing to another

Freedictionary.com

> continually shifting or rapidly changing; having a marked tendency to change
>   e.g. a kaleidoscopic and fractured view of Los Angeles

Answer (score 2):

“[Unpredictable](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unpredictable?s=ts)” comes pretty close, I think.

Unpredictability can be seen as a negative, especially by those who thrive on certainty, i.e., repetitiveness, but as long you’re not referring to its tendency to unpredictably crash or freeze, I think an unpredictable game would be considered **dynamic** and **ever-changing** (2 more suggestions).

Answer (score 2):

If you're not dead-set against phrases, you could use the following to describe the game:

> This game **[never gets old](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=never%20gets%20old).**

If you want to highlight the fact that there is always something new to do in it, you could use:

> This game is **inventive.**

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inventive):

**inventive**: Having the ability to create or design new things or to think originally

Answer (score 1):

There's really not a distinct antonym for repetitive. But here are a few of your options:

[Exciting, lively, interesting](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/repetitive)

[Sporadic, non-repetitive](http://www.powerthesaurus.org/repetitive/antonyms)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **"involving"**

- "It's a very involving game."
- "It's a very involving thing, you get lost in it."

> - involve (vb) To occupy or engage the interest of: a story that completely involved me for the rest of the evening. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/involve)

Comment: *Varied*, *nonrepetitive*.

Comment: @Drew - Yeah, "non-repetitive" is obviously the antonym.  You should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The gaming term is that the game has a big *replay value*

[Replay value - wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_value)